# Choice of primary key for mysql database for fast updates

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I need to create a table which stores '**events**' from different clients, each event has a **event_id**. The event_id is unique for a specific client, implies that the combination of event_id(integer) and client(varchar) can be made a primary key. I intend to use this table as a data provider for my Java application which uses hibernate. The use cases will be adding of events, updating of events and processing the events to generate reports.

I want to ensure fast and accurate update, which requires fetching of the exact row and updating it in hibernate.

Please advice what should be the primary key:

1. Create a primary_key using event_id and client column
2. Create a additional id column with auto_increment and create a unique index using event_id and client

I am confused whether to create a **id** with auto_increment column or not.

Comment: Prefer non-functional, single-column, purely technical, autogenerated primary keys.

Comment: @JB Nizet: In that case i need to put logic to decide whether a row exist or not in db. Will that not slow the save/update process? Lets assume I get 1 event per minute, which means I get 1440 events per day from a single client, if I have 3 clients the number of rows will be 1440*3, the number of rows will grow quickly over few days/months.  Once I receive a event I need to figure out if a update or save is required I want to decide on a table structure which makes this insert/update logic simpler and fast? Although I am not sure if making a combined key will result in good performance?

Comment: Whether the event_id + client is the primary key or not doesn't change anything: you have to check if the row exists anyway. The performance will depend on whether an index is defined or not for the event_id + client. Not whether it's the PK or not.

Comment: @JB Nizet: Ok, so what was the reason to suggest a non-functional,single-column, autogenerated keys. In what way will the application benefit from it? An extra column will only mean more space. Since I won't be able to use this column to fetch the exact row, what way will it be useful? On the other hand if I create a key from client+event_id I can straight away check if the row exist or not?

Comment: Because the rest of your application will be able to reference the client event by a single numerical ID rather than by the combination of two informations, one of them being textual. Because if you add a third information to the functional key of an event later, or change the value of your textual client IDs, you won't have to alter all the tables having a foreign key to the client event table. Because accessing an event by a single-column, numeric PK is faster than accessing it by a composite, textual one. Becouse the Hibernate mapping and the code using it will be much easier to write, etc.

Comment: @JB Nizet: Accepted,Please answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comments from JB Nizet

Prefer non-functional, single-column, purely technical, autogenerated primary keys.
Because the rest of your application will be able to reference the client event by a single numerical ID rather than by the combination of two information's, one of them being textual. Because if you add a third information to the functional key of an event later, or change the value of your textual client IDs, you won't have to alter all the tables having a foreign key to the client event table. Because accessing an event by a single-column, numeric PK is faster than accessing it by a composite, textual one. Because the Hibernate mapping and the code using it will be much easier to write, etc.